# ACL is not supported in Mono (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, acl

I have a problem trying using NamedPipe in Unity3D:
My project requires to communicate with other application, i found out NamedPipe from Microsoft documentation, but while i am starting the project in the editor it throw me that exception ("NotImplementedException: ACL is not supported in Mono")

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but when I set the `TokenImpersonationLevel` to `None` the issue went away.